# Проблема с обновлением линукса с live cd

Tags: linux, обновление, live-usb

На линуксе (kali linux) не работал интернет, и я решил его обновить. Подключился с live cd. Перешёл в папку нужного диска, открыл консоль, ввёл следующие команды:

```bsh
mount -o bind /dev dev
mount -o bind /sys sys
mount -o bind /proc proc
chroot .
```

Дальше `sudo su`, ну и `apt update && apt full-upgrade`.

Вроде бы всё получилось нормально, но когда я перезагрузил компьютер, иконка интернета на нижней панели вообще пропала, так же как и иконка линукса, вдобавок консоль стала выглядеть странно.
В общем, что-то пошло не так. Как мне по-нормальному обновить систему? Я сделал что-то не то?

Comment: Избавиться от кали и поставить нормальный обычный линукс, например убунту. Почитайте [раз](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/395855), [два](https://www.kali.org/docs//introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat очень умный совет, спасибо. Может, лучше на вопрос ответите?

Comment: Если бы знал, то ответил бы. Можете попытать счастья на https://unix.stackexchange.com/ , но даже они не любят вопросы про кали. Посмотрите первую ссылку.

Comment: Вот вам [еще в тему](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5365/395855): *"Due to the nature/instability of Kali, and being it a rolling release often it may make more sense reinstalling the latest version from scratch than upgrading/investing time into fixing it when you face update problems - and facing problems in updates is more the norm than the exception;"*

Comment: В целом, все верно вы сделали, и система должна обновиться. Можно проверить через `less /var/log/apt/history.log` - там будет что обновилось. Или `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz` если прошло время. Чтобы починить интернет, нужно править конфиги. А обновление системы их скорее всего не починит, там же не просто так накатывается все поверх старого.